# Need Transitioning Help from iOS SDK 4 to 5

Tags: xcode4, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

can you still build applications you made from SDK 4 to an updated iOS 5 device?
without having to update to the beta version of XCode (4.2)?

Or maybe, Will it be okay also if I will just have two versions of XCode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update to Xcode 4.2 to get the latest version of the iOS SDK. I'm not sure if you can use the iOS 5 SDK with Xcode 4.1; maybe if you update your compiler to clang 3.0.

Of course, you can always run iOS 4 apps on iOS 5 devices.

Comment: but will it be okay also if I will just have two versions of XCode?

Comment: @BacalsoVincent you mean next to each other? I think it will, I have both Xcode 4.2 and Xcode 3 installed and it works great.

Comment: great! ok, how about, i have xcode 4.0.2 now, and my friend updated his phone to iOS 5, will i be able to build in his device my project with a deployment target of 4.x? or do i really need to have sdk 5? just being nervous on doing things hehe :D

Comment: You can build an iOS 4 app and it will run on an iOS 5 device, yes.